# Codenameone - how to listen for cell selection on a table?

Tags: codenameone

In Codenameone is there a way of detecting when a cell in a table has been clicked so I can find out what the user has selected? I was looking for something like an addActionListener on the cell but can't find one, is there something else?

Comment: Excellent, just what I needed, works a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table isn't editable (in an editable table the cells are text fields) this should be pretty easy:

```
Form hi = new Form("Table", new BorderLayout());
Table clickTable = new Table(new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"AAA", "BBB"}, new String[][] {
    {"Row 1 A", "Row 1 B"},
    {"Row 2 A", "Row 2 B"},
    {"Row 3 A", "Row 3 B"},
})) {

    @Override
    protected Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable) {
        if(editable) {
            return super.createCell(value, row, column, editable);
        }
        Button b = new Button("" + value);
        b.addActionListener(e -> ToastBar.showMessage("Clicked " + row + ", " + column, FontImage.MATERIAL_INFO));
        return b;
    }

};

hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, clickTable);
hi.show();
```

[image: Table with clicks]